# Python Django сайт работает без staticfiles

Tags: python, html, css, django

писал проект на python django около недели, все было нормально, применялись все изменения в css файле, а сегодня проект перестал реагировать на изменения в styles.css и более того, проект начал работать и показывать верстку из того файла, который я уже удалил из staticfiles. Я слышал про то что django хранит данные в оперативной памяти, но я не знаю что с этим делать D:

Comment: Во-первых, Django не хранит файлы в оперативной памяти. Во-вторых, покажите все настройки связанные со статическими файлами и расположения этих самых файлов, иначе непонятно о чём вообще вести речь

Comment: Покажите настройки проекта, попробуйте почистить кэш и отключить `adblock`.

Comment: @andreymal
Настройки - https://pastebin.com/nAHnfTHW
папка static находится в \VimeAI DJANGO\main\static (VimeAI DJANGO - корневая папка проекта)

Answer (score 0):

помогло указание полной директории папки static, просто "/static/" не работало.